# Granting all permissions to mysql schemas that start with a specific set of characters

Tags: mysql, ddl

I am trying to grant CRUD permissions on any SCHEMA that starts with a specific set of characters.  I'm doing this with MySQL 8.x

Here is the example query I'm attempting to execute :

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON 'tc4_%'.* TO specific_user;
```

I want any Schema that is prefixed with `tc4_` to have CRUD privileges.  These schemas are yet to be created, so I can't explicitly assign the privileges explicitly before they are created.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You must grant privileges on the tables in each schema *after* you create the schema. And, you cannot use that `LIKE`-style wildcard.

This SQL will generate a result set containing your GRANT operations applying the wildcard.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
       'GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ', 
        SCHEMA_NAME, 
        '.* TO ''username''@''hostname'';') cmd
  FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
 WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'te%'
UNION ALL SELECT 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES;' cmd   /* this line is optional */
```

Comment: Good answer, but it should be unnecessary to FLUSH PRIVILEGES after a GRANT. Flushing privileges does no harm, but it's needed only if you write to the system tables directly with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. GRANT/REVOKE should take care of that implicitly.